# foreach Razor values to external javascript file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to send foreach razor values to external js script.At this moment my Razor forEach is in inside  tag inside html file, It´s work normally, but in this moment its needs put  tag on external file.

```js
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return  '<b>' + this.series.name +' : </b>' +
                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y/3600000,2);
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Hours',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [

        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Horas)
        {
                 @:  [  "@item.Key", @item.Value ],
        }


        ]
        }]

});
```

Comment: Make an API Controller and get values via ajax. Otherwise, just serialize the data and shove it in a hidden dom node then grab with JavaScript. Why? Because this degree of nesting is bad for maintainability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the value from your C# expression inside your razor file (where you can execute C# code) and pass that to the external javascript code.

So add that code to your view file.

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var myApp = myApp || {};
        var a = [];
        @{
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.Horas as Dictionary<string, string>)
            {
                @:a.push(['@item.Key', '@item.Value']);
            }
        }
        myApp.dataArray = a;
    </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/yourExternalJsFile.js"></script>
}
```

and now in `yourExternalJsFile.js` file, you may access it like `myApp.dataArray`

```
(function ($, window, myApp) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        console.log('the data array', myApp.dataArray);    
        // Use this to initialize your chart
    });
})(jQuery, window, myApp);
```

Update the [`IIFE`](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) part to pass your other dependencies as needed

Comment: The only difference between this and the OP is that you're generating imperative JavaScript, not declarative JavaScript.